# How to categorize a customer service check on accounting books?

Tags: real-estate, accounting, customer-service

I'm trying to help out a friend with their bookkeeping for a real estate investment they just purchased.  I'm pretty sure I have categorized all the closing expenses properly except for one thing.  The bank messed up some things during the closing process and then mailed a check a week or two after closing to apologize.  How would one categorize this transaction (e.g. revenue, a negative expense)?  My friend is in TX, USA.

Comment: I tried to answer the best I could. If you stated your country and/or state, it could get into more detail.

Comment: My friend's transaction was in TX, USA

Comment: This question is a perfect fit for the Accounting site (currently a proposal in Area 51: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113560/accounting?referrer=FNOG9_mXNYnhlAdnl9FE8w2 )

Answer (score 1):

It might be an [indemnity](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/indemnity.asp) depending on your jurisdiction (that you don't state at the time of this writing).

From investopedia:

> Indemnity is compensation for damages or loss.

So the bank probably caused a loss (of time, etc) to your friend, and compensated with that check.

You should check with an accountant if Indemnity is taxed differently from other sources of income, or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that any corrections would be a negative expense as it was a honest mistake by the bank provided the jurisdiction was the United States.

Comment: A few comments: (1) The question does not state a request for tax advice, just accounting. (2) There is no indication of jurisdiction in the OP, so providing broad tax advice like this may be wrong in a particular jurisdiction, even if it is correct in your own.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I've corrected my answer. Any other comments?

Comment: It is good that you provided a proviso for jurisdiction, but note that accounting principles (which the OP asked about) do not necessarily follow tax principles.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon IANAA so I will defer on the tax implication but believe I'm still on good ground with respect to accounting practice (and if not - please elucidate in an answer or a comment to the OP for more info)